# Why my custom PermissionEvaluator isn't invoked?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm struggling with my Spring Security configuration which I wasn't able to make it works so far.
I don't know why my custom PermissionEvaluator is not getting invoked and my @PreAuthorize annotation using hasPermission expression are ignored.

I'm using Spring 4.2.4 and Spring security 4.1.0

Her is my code :

**Web Security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http //
                .addFilterBefore(wafflePreAuthFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class) //
                .authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider()) //
                .csrf().disable() //
                .authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/ui/**").authenticated() //
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public WafflePreAuthFilter wafflePreAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        WafflePreAuthFilter filter = new WafflePreAuthFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        preauthAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper());
        return preauthAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsServiceWrapper() {
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>();
        wrapper.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService());
        return wrapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService() {
        return new myUserDetailsService();
    }
}
```

**Method Security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MyServiceMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public PermissionEvaluator myPermissionEvaluator() {
        return new DcePermissionEvaluator();
    }

    @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(myPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

**PermissionEvaluator**

```
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myAutowiredService;

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        // checking permissions
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        // checking permissions
        return true;
    }
}
```

Anyone can give me an hint on what to do ?

By the way if I change MyServiceMethodSecurityConfig into this, then myPermissionEvaluator is processed but dependencies injection doesn't work as it isn't managed by Spring :

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = false)
public class MyServiceMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new DcePermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any progress on thiz?

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue. It seemed to be caused by the annotation @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity being specified in multiple places.

Once I removed it from locations other than above my implementation of GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration things started working as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the same issue and it cost me HOURS to find a solution. Removing all `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotations except for one does the trick. Interestingly, it worked with multiple annotations when running under linux, but not under windows.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will spend more hours if didn't found your answer. @Alan47 BTW I my case it reproduced in Mac, but not under windows.